# Code Sign error - Iphone Debuggin

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging

I have big problems.

I'm new on a small company and now I'm in charge of the iPhone developing.

Because I'm new and everything isn't clear on my work area (I had 7 Provisioning Profiles, for example), and I wanted to restart, so I opened the Keychain Access and deleted all Certificates, all My Certificates and all Keys.

Now I know it was a mistake I deleted my Keys, right?.

I went to Apple Developer Site and download all the Provisioning Profiles and Certificates, but I can´t make it work.

When I try to debug on my Real Device, it shows me "Code Sign error: The identity 'XXXXX' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain" error.

After reading over the internet I think my problem was deleting the keys, right?. 
I lost the key for the certificate, right?
What can I do?

The system's previus version is on the Apple Market, so I can't delete the certificate and create a new one, no?

I really need help. I'm new and this proccess is really difficult for me.

Thanks and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Was that Mac backed up at any point? Did the previous developer(s) keep another copy of the private key somewhere else?

Comment: Nop. I don't make backup. I didn't becouse ask me for a password and I didn't have. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can savely revoke the certificates in the provisioning portal and recreate them with a new private key. This won't affect already released apps. After that just sign your apps with the new created certificates that match your new private key.

Just follow the steps on the "How To" tab in the provisioning portal if you get stuck.

Comment: there is not problem with the app already released??. I have to do something with thats?. There is not cost at all?

Comment: Only certificates? o Profiles too?

Comment: You sure have to pay to get into the developer program itself, otherwise you won't be able to create certificates! Other than the yearly fee the revokation and creation of new certificates is free. Already released apps are not affected by the revokation, you can release update to an app with another key/certificate pair.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I can help you, as I am also new, but still making a try ..
First, you yourself understand that you should not delete ALL profiles from keychain. But, you may, certainly, delete the profiles that get expired (it shows a small red cross on the profile name if it gets expired). Now, though you have deleted all from keychain, you CAN get them back. You must have a *.cer file as you downloaded all profiles from developer site. You also have a *.p12 file. On click on both to use the certificates. In one case, you will need to provide password (I don't remember which case, sorry). Put the password and you will find them in keychain.

Now, connect your device to Mac, collect also the information to the device using Organizer. To open organizer, go to Xcode->Window->Organizer. Here, click on Devices. On the left pane, You'll see 'Provisional profiles'. Click on it. Now you can see which provisional profiles are installed. Click on any one of them. Note the app identifier. It may be in this format 'ABCDEF.com.YourCompany.*' . Copy this part 'com.YourCompany.' and paste it in your code->info->Bundle Identifier (before $PRODUCT_NAME).

In build settings, now you'll be able to find the developer profile.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, some parts I already know. 
My problem are the private keys of my certificates. I lost that. If I see the keychain, all the certificate doesn't have the "triangle" with the private key.